# Executing multiline query does not work with table alias where single-line query does

Tags: eclipse, ms-access, hsqldb, ucanaccess

This is my first time using ucanaccess since I just found out that my previous version of Eclipse would not work with Java 1.8 so I can get to my Access DB. I am familiar with Java programming and RDBMS (currently use Oracle) so I don't understand why I'm getting an error with my code.

This is the code I use to connect to the DB (variable dbFile is a File object used to store the Access DB path):

```js
  try
  {
   String urlDB = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+ dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
   
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB, "", "");
   System.out.println("Connection Successful\n");
   
   Statement test = conn.createStatement();
/*   ResultSet rs = test.executeQuery("SELECT e.* "
                                                       + "FROM Employees e"
                                                       + "WHERE e.EmployeeNo LIKE 'H%'" 
                                                       + "ORDER BY e.LastName");

   System.out.println(); //spacing

   //retrieve column data
   while(rs.next())
   {
    //can get data by column name instead of ID
    String id = rs.getString("ID");
    String fName = rs.getString("FirstName");
    String lName = rs.getString("LastName");
    String dName = rs.getString("DisplayName");
      
    System.out.println(id + "\t" + fName + "\t" + lName + "\t");
    
   }
*/   
   ResultSet rs = test.executeQuery("SELECT e.* FROM Employees e WHERE e.EmployeeNo LIKE '1%' ORDER BY e.LastName");
   
   //get table information (i.e. column names)
   ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
   int dbColumnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
   
/*   //db columns starts at 1 not 0
   for (int count = 1; count <= dbColumnCount; count++)
   {
    System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnName(count) + "\t");
   }
*/   
   System.out.format("%5s%10s%15s%20s%n", rsmd.getColumnName(1), rsmd.getColumnName(2),
     rsmd.getColumnName(3), rsmd.getColumnName(4));
   //System.out.println();
   
   while(rs.next())
   {
    //can get data by column name instead of ID
    String id = rs.getString("ID");
    String fName = rs.getString("FirstName");
    String lName = rs.getString("LastName");
    String dName = rs.getString("DisplayName");
      
    //System.out.println(id + "\t" + fName + "\t" + lName + "\t");
    System.out.format("%5s%10s%15s%20s%n", id, fName, lName, dName);
   }
   
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.err.println("Could not connect to the Database");
   System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  }  
 }
```

The first call to ResultSet(multiline query) throws the following exception:

```js
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.0 user lacks privilege or object not found: E
 at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:210)
 at DBConnect.<init>(InOutBoard.java:78)
 at InOutBoard.main(InOutBoard.java:47)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: E
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
 at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:208)
 ... 2 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: E
 at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveColumnReferencesForAsterisk(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveReferences(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
 at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
 ... 5 more
Could not connect to the Database
UCAExc:::4.0.0 user lacks privilege or object not found: E
```

whereas if I run the second call to ResultSet (single-line query), the data is properly returned from the table. Now as far as I can tell (other than spanning multiple lines in the first one) both queries are the same. So why is it that the first one throws the error? I can't imagine that the choice of formatting would make a difference, but as I said, I'm knew to using ucanaccess.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link I regularly give is valid here too:
[How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

You are concatenating a SQL string without checking it is correct.

```
ResultSet rs = test.executeQuery("SELECT e.* "
                               + "FROM Employees e"
                               + "WHERE e.EmployeeNo LIKE 'H%'" 
                               + "ORDER BY e.LastName");
```

will result in

```
SELECT e.* FROM Employees eWHERE e.EmployeeNo LIKE 'H%'ORDER BY e.LastName
```

It's missing spaces between the line breaks.

Comment: Wow - this is why I should have walked away from the program and came back to it later. Sorry for that and thanks for showing me this error. +1 for the link too - very helpful